# Why return statement is explicitly required in function?

Tags: go

When the compiler is aware of what it returns (fullName in the example), why it expects explicit return statement?

```
func fullName(firstName string, lastName string) (fullName string) {
    fullName = firstName + " " + lastName
    return // Why explicit return?
}
```

Comment: This is called a ["naked return"](https://tour.golang.org/basics/7) by the way. Although usually the answer to most "why is the language designed this way" questions is "because that's how it was designed".

Comment: Because the function has a return value. As for asking _why_, because the specification says so. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/32880

Comment: @Alexander - there is even an [open proposal to remove this from go](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21291).

Comment: What if you want to return in multiple conditions?

Comment: @meshkati That's a conditional return statement.

Comment: @Alexander The word `explicit` I used to denote why Go required it forcefully/manually?

Comment: You could ask the inverse, why are we allowed to have implicit return in void functions?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco You're making some joke (implicit...)...what we mostly expect them.

Comment: I'm not trying to make a joke, I'm trying to illuminate that explicit returns are the rule, not the exception.  A function without explicit return is only allowed in specific circumstances, that being a void function (also nonsense cases like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/QVIAd4XE18U)).  It might be worth asking why it's allowed in the case of voids, even though the compiler still needs to generate the return instruction(s).

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Okay. I got your point. :)

Answer (score 2):

As others said, I think you should not only slow down on this path, but actually stop and reverse. I think Go is a great language, but the "naked return" is just a bad syntax to use. Look at this example:

```
package main
import "strconv"

func parse() (i int64, err error) {
   {
      // i is shadowed during return
      // err is shadowed during return
      i, err := strconv.ParseInt("100", 10, 64)
      return
   }
}

func main() {
   parse()
}
```

So if you have any level of depth in your code, which is highly likely, then the naked return totally fails. Maybe someone has a good use case for them, but I don't use them at all, as they just seem to add more trouble for little benefit.

Answer (score 2):

To cite an explicit reason, here's the actual rule from the spec that is most relevent

[Go language specification: Functions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations)

> If the function's signature declares result parameters, the function body's statement list must end in a [terminating statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Terminating_statements).

Read the link for "terminating statement" to see the comprehensive list.  Notice that though they are called "terminating", all except for `return` (and `panic`...) are statements that will **never terminate**.

So another way of interpreting the rule is this (ignoring `panic`...):

> A function with return types must terminate by returning values, or never terminate at all.

This means that functions like this are legal too:

```golang
func get() string {
    for {
        fmt.Println("not returning yet")
    }
}
```

Despite declaring a return type, this function `get` will provably never terminate, so it doesn't need a return statement.

What is the *motivation* of this rule?  That question is both opinion and speculation based. It falls under the principle of "clear is better than clever", which is also a [Go Proverb](https://go-proverbs.github.io/).

Look at this strange situation created by `panic` and `recover`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func get() (s string) {
    defer func() {
        err  := recover()
        fmt.Println("recovered error:", err)
    }()
    
    s = "hi"

    panic("terminating panic")
}

func main() {
    s := get()
    fmt.Println("s =", s)
}
```

output:

```
recovered error: terminating panic
s = hi
```

You'll notice that `get` has no return statement, yet it is able to return this value `"hi"`.